# How to find a substring in a given field in mongodb with python eve?

Tags: mongodb, rest, eve

I am trying to query mongodb database using a string and return all docs which contains that string. I am using javascript in my front and python eve as rest api.

Javascript code

```
function load1(){
    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:5000/people/?where = {"lastname":{"$regex":"^(?i)*vanity"}}',function(data,status){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: I have already added MONGO_QUERY_BLACKLIST = ['$where', '$regex'] to my settings.py

Comment: One way to do this is using mongo's wildcard text index (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes) and eve's fetch event hook to filter the results using `$text` search (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text).

Comment: show your code please